# Find Markov policy that minimizes(maximizes) the expected discounted cost(reward)

Tags: markov-process, dynamic-programming

It's an exam problem I found online.Here's a [link](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/people/faculty/Hayriye_Ayhan/exam208.pdf) to the pastpaper.

The problem is stated as follows.

A repairman who services Q facilities moves between location s and
location j according to the transition probability p(j|s). An equipment trailer
which carries parts may be located at any one of M sites. If the trailer is at
site m and the repairman is at facility j, the cost of obtaining material from
the trailer is c(m,j). The cost of moving the trailer from site m to j is d(m,j).
The decision maker's objective is to dynamically relocate the trailer so as to
minimize the expected cost. Assume that the decision maker observes the location of the repairman and trailer, relocates the trailer and then the repairman
moves and services a facility. Formulate this as an infnite horizon discounted
Markov Decision Process problem. Does there exist a Markovian deterministic
policy which is optimal? Justify your answer.

I think it is possible to tackle the problem using the value iteration method. But I am not sure how exactly I can formulate this problem into a Markov decision process.

Any explanation would be appreciated.